# Angular 4/5 Dynamic Component, create new Instance

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dynamic, view

I'm trying to create a dynamic dashboard. Right now I'm using this dynamicServer to inject the component, but when I display the same component a second time, the information is shared between. I'm trying to isolate the "views" and create a new instance. Any help?

**dynamicServer.ts**

```
loadComponent(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
const childComponent = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.resolveView(this.ViewtoInjet));
const instance = viewContainerRef.createComponent(childComponent).instance;    
}
```

**ViewContainer.ts**

```
  @ViewChild('dynamic', {
  read: ViewContainerRef
    }) viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(@Inject(DynamicServiceTestService) service, private winRef: 
  WindowRefService) {
  this.service = service;
    }

ngOnInit() {
this.service.loadComponent(this.viewContainerRef);
}
```

[Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q33Et.png)

As you can see, I am rendering the same component twice, but if I click to add numbers with the buttons, the value is shared between them. Any way to generate a new instance of every component to isolate them?

**EDIT**

I add a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpryfl?file=src/app/view-container/view-container.component.ts

When i put my code in stackblitz i realized that my code was ok!!, but in my computer code i was using a service to refresh the counter, so it was ok so the counter in the service has to be common, but now ive got another question.

Is it possible to open 2 references of the same component, so if i add numbers in one component will i see the changes in the copy of the same component?

Comment: Can you reproduce it on stackblitz?

Comment: Edit :), added stackblitz, and another question